# Is there a way to check if a page exists in the navigation stack

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the RemoveBackEntry() method to remove two pages from my Navigation stack. The problem is I now want to implement more features which will change the stack.

I was wondering is there is a way to remove pages based on the PageName or even if there is a way to check for the pages existence in the Navigation Stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the backstack´s ElementAt(i).Source equals the page name. And you can delete it if it does.